# Liquid Maths issue

Tags: shopify, liquid

So, I'm trying to do a simple maths equation in liquid code for my Shopify website, in order to show a m² price for each product.

The code should just be:

```
£{{ product.price | divided_by: product.metafields.custom.coverage | money_without_currency }} per m²
```

This works when it's located in its own Snippet, and rendered into the Price.Liquid file. But if I try to place this directly into the Price.Liquid file, it returns an error that's it's dividing by zero.

It seems that the `product.price` returns the correct figure, but the `product.metafields.custom.coverage` wont return that number.

For example:

`{{ product.price | divided_by: 2 }}` will bring a correct result without an error.

Can anyone help with a workaround? Or at least tell me that this is a no go, so that I can move on! :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The above code that you have posted should work fine given that everything it needs does exist.

```
£{{ product.price | divided_by: product.metafields.custom.coverage | money_without_currency }} per m²
```

Based on the theme you are using, it is **possible** that inside the **Price.liquid** file, the product variable is being overridden with variant. With something like

```
{% assign product = product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
```

In this case, the product variable is referring to selected or first **variant** and the meta field does not exist on **variant**. It is configured on **product** level.

And if you use it inside some other snippet, the product variable refers to original product object and it works fine.

Besides this, it would be advisable to have an if check to prevent such errors, in case the meta field does not exist

```
  {% if product.metafields.custom.coverage > 0 %}}
    £{{ product.price | divided_by: product.metafields.custom.coverage | money_without_currency }} per m²
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've sorted this now. :)